# SetEnv is not working in vhost

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I'm trying to do a `SetEnv foo bar` in my virtual hosts file but I can never get it to work properly. I'm on a LAMP stack. I've checked that my `mod_env` has been enabled via `sudo a2enmod env` and it's enabled fine. Running `php -i` will not list `$_SERVER['foo']`. I've tried it on my local machine and a production server, still same results. Is there something I'm missing?

I've restarted `sudo service apache2 restart` without any warnings, so `SetEnv` would be parsed fine I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

php -i won't list this, as php on your server isn't going through apache..

try and write a script:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and put this at your virtualhost root directory, and run this file.. you will surely see your environment variable in the info,

Answer (score 0):

If you have php-fpm you should put your env variables inside conf file in pool.d/ folder as this.

```
[www]
env[ENVIRONMENT] = 'VAR'
```